# FFMPEG CROP BLACK BARS BAD QUALITY

Tags: ffmpeg

Hello im using this command to remove the black bars and make the video fullscreen ,

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -vf "crop=1920:800:0:140,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1" -c:v h264_nvenc -rc:v vbr_hq -cq:v 0 -b:v 27000k -maxrate:v 26000k -profile:v high -preset slow og1.mkv
```

It works good , 
But the problem is the quality of the video, there is a lot of difference between the original and the new,and apart from that it's like the video is a bit stretched because of the new crop settings.

Comment: If you want to avoid the stretch, scale to `-1:1080` and then crop to `1920:1080`

Comment: As for the quality, does libx264 produce better quality?

Comment: @Gyan tried that and didnt worked "ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -vf crop="1920:800:0:140",scale=--1:1080 out.mp4
" , when i change to scale=--1:1080 not works , with scale=--1920:1080 works , but stretched